# Android export ends with a failed buildDebugPreBundle task error in Godot 4.1

Tags: android, gradle, godot, gradle-plugin, godot4

I really need your help. Recently, I tried to export a game for Android devices known as *Bounceroids* with Use Gradle Build and plugins enabled many times after completing the requirements for exporting Android project in Godot 4.1. However, it ends up with a failed buildDebugPreBundle task, and the error message popped up. For those who want to know what caused this problem, then here is the following log below:

```
> Task :buildDebugPreBundle FAILED

FAILUREL Build failed with an exception.

*What went wrong:
Execution failed for task 'buildDebugPreBundle'.
> Unable to allocate 78596352 bytes

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
33 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 32 up-to-date

Exit Code: 1
```

Darn, this error sucks. So I really need a proper solution in order to fix this problem. Do you have any ideas? Let me know your answer in this topic. Thanks.

Execution failed for task 'buildDebugPreBundle'.

Comment: well did you do what the error message suggested? any of the options it gives, would lead to more informations on what went wrong...